# Anyone knows about text-based emotion detection systems that offer a demo?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, demo

I recently finished work on my text-based emotion detection engine and I am looking for other existing working systems to compare with mine in order to know what should be improved and also report comparisons in an upcoming paper.

I have come across many companies claiming to do emotion detection from text but only this one offers a demo that I can use to compare with my system: http://www.o2mc.io/portfolio-posts/text-analysis-restful-api-language-polarity-and-emotion/ (scroll all the way down to see the "try it yourself" section).

Please notice that I am not looking for polarity classification, which is the simpler task of saying if a text is positive or negative. What I am looking for is for emotions (sadness, anger, joy, etc...). Does anyone here know about any company/university/person offering a demo to such system?
As a reference, here is the link to my own system's demo:
http://demo.soulhackerslabs.com/emotion/

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This might be helpful https://medium.com/@sifium/top-five-emotional-sentiment-analysis-apis-116cd8d42055